# Autowiring not working inside flyway callback methods

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I am trying to flyway for the migration demo. In which I am able to migrate code.  I have extended BaseFlywayCallback and I want to print migration info before and after each migration. I have code in other service class for printing info. I am auto wiring it but it is not working there. I have tried some other ways but nothing worth it.

```
  @Autorired
  PrintInfoService service
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integration with flyway internally in spring boot is done by means of using [FlywayAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration.java)

It has to create a `Flyway` bean on which it will register all callbacks found in the classpath.

I can't test this, but you I believe you have to:

1. Make sure that your callback is a spring bean
2. Make sure that spring boot scans your bean and create an instance of it during the initialization
3. Place a breakpoint in the `FlywayAutoConfiguration`'s:

```
public Flyway flyway(FlywayProperties properties, DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties,
                ResourceLoader resourceLoader, ObjectProvider<DataSource> dataSource,
                @FlywayDataSource ObjectProvider<DataSource> flywayDataSource,
                ObjectProvider<FlywayConfigurationCustomizer> fluentConfigurationCustomizers,
                ObjectProvider<JavaMigration> javaMigrations, ObjectProvider<Callback> callbacks)
```

4. ... And make sure that your callback is in the list of beans recognized by spring.